# Rename file in XP, only select file name, but show file extension

Tags: windows-xp, rename, filenames, file-extension

So if I have a file called: test.txt and I want to rename it, there are two options (depending on the Show already known file extension option):

1) ON: 
it selects everything (test.txt), meaning I have to manually select "test" and replace it with the new filename. (which is irritating)

2) OFF:
Only "test" is editable (and visible).

Problem is that I frequently need to change the file extension of a file, but if the option is turned on, it's a pain to change the file name.

I know that in Win7 it does something smart: It only selects the file name when you press rename[F2], but also lets you edit the file extension.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Or you could re-type `.txt`, which is several times faster than manually selecting and replacing "test".

Comment: Sure, but that's not a very good solution at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pitaschio](http://pitaschio.ara3.net/) has that feature (among a bunch of others).

If you're looking for *only* that feature, there's also [TheEnd](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#TheEnd), which is a nicely packaged AutoHotkey script to do the same thing.

I've seen other tools as well to add that feature to Explorer, but can't hunt any of them down right now.

Finally, you could use an Explorer replacement.  Unfortunately, most of them tend to suck in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer > Tools > Folder Options > View > tag the box labeled "Hide extensions of known file types"

That's not perfect but gets most of what you're asking for. It does make it much easier to rename files without having to deal with the extensions.

Comment: What if the *known file type* extensions also should be edited?